# Currently refactoring my Firestore post data function into an array storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I have a dashboard application and when a user adds to their dashboard it does a post request to Firestore to set the data in a certain document. Here is what that code looks like:

```
export function createEntry(data) { // Data has a authorId key with the value of the UID
  const userEntry = firestore.collection('userEntries').doc();
  userEntry.set(data);
  return userEntry;
}
```

So above, a new entry gets created with a random ID that I  then use to grab the data to display later. To get this information later, I loop through all of the entries to see where the authorId matches the user that is log in to return that.

So what I am trying to do is refactor the code so that each document in 'userEntries' is the ID of the user, authorID: UID, and have it be an array where I can keep pushing items into. In return, I can just grab the user array and map over those items to display instead of looping through all my entries and checking.

What I've tried:

```
export function createEntry(data) {
  const userEntry = firestore.collection('userEntries').doc(data.authorId);
  userEntry.update({ 
    userData: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data)
  })
}
```

So to sum it up, I would like a way to set the document to users ID and push any future entries into their own array, in which I could easily access from the frontend to display.

Hope you can point me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to revise the original method. If you have the `authorId` as a field value, you can just query the data using `where` clause like this:

```
const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
firestore.collection().where('authorId', '==', uid).get();
```

With this method, you are not getting the entire collection and looping through to see which one is written by the user.

Comment: Hey I apologize for the late reply. So currently users are created in a 'users' collection. When an entry is made that is made in a 'userEntries' collection and the document is set with a random id. In that userEntrie document there is an authorId that points back to the author. So from the frontend I'm going through and checking each userEntry where it matches the current user logged in. Am I missing something on how Firestore works or is that still looping through each one to check?

Comment: @MyPalVikram Yes, you are actually missing how billing works in firestore. You don't want to load all documents and loop through them and go through each, because you will be loading a lot of excessive documents. Firestore will charge you for each document you load, so your billing will be super high with your method. With my method, you are only loading those documents that are written by the user, so it's cheaper, and it uses less data.